# Moving HTML and SCSS from page to component

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, components, ionic3

By moving HTML and SCSS from page to component, the whole design got messed up completely and I'm not sure why. Re-writing all of my SCSS from zero seems like a bit of an extra workload. I'm wondering if there something I'm missing where the inner HTML and SCCS of some page of a page, which was not moved to a component needs to be changed in order to make the design look good again?

Comment: Moving HTML to component? What do you mean. Please provide some example

Comment: @Duannx I'm just moving all the HTML/SCSS/TS from a page to a component. Basically converting part of a page(which is the same across many other pages) into a component to be re-used more easily across other pages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was extremely annoying. Basically, your component must have 2 part name like “listingItem”, it can’t be just “listing”. I might have missed it, but haven’t seen this in the documentation (which Ionic doesn’t have, and haven’t looked too deep in Angular).

Takeaway: “firstSecond” is a good name, a bad name is “first”

Comment: Yes. It’s their that or the word “listing” was reserved. When I generated a new component named “listingItem”, worked like a charm.